# Prefix-function computation in Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, substring, knuth-morris-pratt

So for the following sub string

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

a b c d a b c d a b  x
```

Which is the prefix function? Me and one of my friends computed it and we have different results, mine is:

```
a b c d a b c d a b x

0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 2
```

and his:

```
a b c d a b c d a b x

0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 1 2 0
```

If I am wrong, why is that?

Comment: Could you add a short outline of what you are looking for. Not all of us have this book lying around...

Comment: The pseudo-code is                                                       m ← length[p]
a[1] ← 0
k ← 0
for q ← 2 to m do
while k > 0 and p[k + 1] , p[q] do
k ← a[k]
end while
if p[k + 1] = p[q] then
k ← k + 1
end if
a[q] ← k
end for
return u

Comment: @user3848412 please put your pseudo-code into your question, it helps other to read and follow your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix table should be:

```
a b c d a b c d a b x
0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0
```

so both versions given are not right.

For the last entry of your table

```
a b c d a b c d a b x
0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 2
                    ^
                    |
                this one
```

to be correct, the suffix of length 2 of `a b c d a b c d a b x` which is `b x` would also have to be its length 2 prefix, which is `a b` instead.

In case of entries different from zero in the prefix table corresponding prefixes and suffixes have been marked in the table below:

```
a                       0
a b                     0
a b c                   0
a b c d                 0

a  b c d a              1
-
         =
a b c d a b             2
---
        ===

a b c d a b c           3
-----
        =====

a b c d a b c d         4
-------
        =======

a b c d a b c d a       5
---------
        =========

a b c d a b c d a b     6
-----------
        ===========

a b c d a b c d a b  x   0
```

Answer (score 1):

My KMP function in java:

```java
public int[] KMP(String val) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = -1;
    int[] result = new int[val.length() + 1];
    result[0] = -1;
    while (i < val.length()) {
        while (j >= 0 && val.charAt(j) != val.charAt(i)) {
            j = result[j];
        }
        j++;
        i++;
        result[i] = j;
    }
    return result;

}
```

Result for prefix arrays:

```
[-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your answers are correct. The prefix function or partial match table would be the following:

```
a b c d a b c d a b x

0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0
```

Your answer was correct upto index 10. But in the last index you have done something wrong. The reason why value of index 11 of partial match table would 0 is because there are no proper prefix which matches any proper suffix of the string upto index 11. Because all proper suffixes at this position will end with x and no proper prefix at this position will end with x.

If you have problem understanding what actually prefix function or partial index table means you can take a look into this [document](http://jakeboxer.com/blog/2009/12/13/the-knuth-morris-pratt-algorithm-in-my-own-words/). It has a very good explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: @user3848412 If it helped you, perhaps an upvote wouldn't do you any harm, would it? :P

Answer (score 1):

both of your answers are wrong. correct one will be

```
a b c d a b c d a b x

0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0
```